# Custom Segmented Control setIndex Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range” when I setselected index

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, segment

I am using this Custom Segmented Control[code](https://github.com/Code-With-Coffee/CustomSegmentedControl/blob/master/CustomSegmentedControl/CustomSegmentedControl.swift) in one of my View. I have one issue when I tried to setIndex I make it public and I passed the number of selected index I get  this error "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range” when I set selected index"

```
  public func setIndex(index: Int) {
        buttons.forEach({ $0.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal) })
        let button = buttons[index]
        selectedIndex = index
        button.setTitleColor(selectorTextColor, for: .normal)
        let selectorPosition = frame.width/CGFloat(buttonTitles.count) * CGFloat(index)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.selectorView.frame.origin.x = selectorPosition
        }
    }
```

Comment: `let button = buttons[index]` cause the crash? What's the `buttons.count` and `index` values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before moving to the functionality, first check wether the `index` is within   the `buttons` array range

```swift
 if index > buttons.count - 1 {
   // Index out of range.
   return
 }
```